# Reference Member Required to be Const?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, constants

In this simple example, why do I need to make 'member' const in order to get this to compile?

```
struct ClassA
{
    ClassA(int integer) {}
};

struct ClassB
{
    ClassB(int integer):
        member(integer)
    {
    }

    const ClassA& member;
};

int main()
{
    ClassB* b = new ClassB(12);

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, I get this error:

> error: invalid initialization of
>   reference of type 'ClassA&' from
>   expression of type 'int'

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating `b`? And your code is unsafe; once the `ClassB` constructor ends, the temporary `ClassA` that was made from `integer` ends its lifetime, and you are referring to nothing.

Comment: No idea why this works with const, but why is "member" a reference? Do you mean to write "ClassA member;"?

Comment: This is maybe an over-simplified example as some people have pointed out, I'm just trying to find the easiest way of expressing the problem. In reality, ClassA is a weighty class that I don't wish to add a compilation dependency, as I only wish to need a forward decleration in the header.

Comment: You'd have to make the parameter for `ClassB`'s constructor a reference to a `ClassA`, though now you have to make sure `ClassB` never lives longer than the `ClassA` passed in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why is that what's actually happening here is you're using an implicit conversion from `int` to `ClassA` in the initialization of `member`.  In expanded form it is actually doing the following

```
member(ClassA(integer))
```

This means that the `ClassA` instance is a temporary.  It's not legal to have a reference to a temporary variable only a const reference hence you get the compiler error.

The easiest fix is to remove the `&` modifier on member and make it just of type `ClassA`

```
ClassA member;
```

Additionally it's a good practice to put `explicit` in front of the `ClassA` constructor to avoid the silent implicit conversion.

```
explicit ClassA(int integer){}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are trying to store a reference to a temporary object, and you may only store *constant* references to temporaries.

When you try to initialize the `member` reference of type `ClassA&` with the `integer` parameter of type `int`, the implicit conversion constructor `ClassA::ClassA(int integer)` is inovked to produce an unnamed temporary object of type `ClassA` from the `integer` variable. That unnamed temporary object is then used to initialize the reference `member`, creating a reference-to-temporary, which must be const.

I question your design here. If you're trying to initialize `member` with data passed by value to the `ClassB` constructor, having `member` be a reference is probably not the right thing to do. Why do you think `member` ought to be a reference and not just an object?

Answer (score 0):

ClassA is a reference member of ClassB, so it must be instantiated with an instance of ClassA.

Comment: There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `ClassA` because of it's single valued constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You're create a temporary, and initializing the reference from that temporary. Just like usual, to bind to a temporary, a reference has to be const.

I'd have serious second thoughts about this. A class with a reference member is rarely useful. When it is useful, you generally want to start with some existing object and pass a reference to that object through to the member reference. When you do this, you *need* to be sure the referenced object exists for the entire lifetime of the object containing a reference, so the two are *quite* tightly coupled -- which you'd usually rather avoid.